# Access Flink data over rest in a Java micoservice

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a usecase where I need to gather the count of events daily, and store this info over a three month window. I was reading about flink counting windows and thought it was a good fit.
I need to be able to serve this aggregated data over a rest API. ie if a user queries the number of events with a date filter from say 1st to 2nd april, my API should be able to serve that.
I'm new to flink and offline processing in general. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

At a high-level, Flink is going to be a tool for populating some persistence layer that your REST API will handle calling in this scenario. There isn't really the concept of "querying" Flink directly (outside of the use of [Queryable State](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/queryable_state/), which is generally a no-no).

What you'd likely do is use Flink to handle [windowing](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/) your data as it passed through your pipeline and then after those windows closed (or however your see fit as you could periodically emit values downstream), you'd use [one of the supported sinks](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/overview/#predefined-sources-and-sinks) to write those counts to some persistent storage (database, cloud storage, etc.). Your API calls would then query out to that persistent data store and serve your counts from there (as opposed to querying Flink).

Windowing in Flink is pretty flexible and already has plenty of functionality built-in for handling the type of windows you are looking for (daily tumbling windows) and allows you to have fine-grained control over when results should be emitted from a window, how to handle late-arriving data, etc.